# Common routes for Razor Page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes, razor-pages

Is there a way to declare a common route for Razor Pages, for example I have `Foo.cshtml` which can be accessed by any of the following Url:

- `/foo`
- `/en/foo`
- `/fr/foo`
- `/bar/foo`

Note: I want this to be applied to all other Razor Page in the project as well.

So I found a solution, however, I want a custom route handler as well, that is, when user lands on the url, depends on the Url, I want to perform different works (changing Thread Culture for example)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Core Razor Page multiple path routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48710826/asp-net-core-razor-page-multiple-path-routing)

Answer (score 1):

you can add a route like

```
  routes.MapRoute("DefaultLocalized",
              "{language}-{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
              new
              {
                  controller = "Home",
                  action = "Index",
                  id = UrlParameter.Optional,
                  language = "en",
                  culture = "US"
              });
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the `Convention` and combine with `PageFilter`. But this one looks interesting, I may try it next time.